# FIFO Stock Inventory with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, fifo, inventory-management

I need an implementation using PostgresSQL of the problem "FIFO Stock Inventory"

Immagine I have a movements table:

| . id | type | qta | buy_price | fifo_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | IN | 12 | 11 - buy 12 units at 11$ |  |
| 2. | OUT | 2. |  | 11 <-- sell 2 unita using last price "11$" |
| 3. | IN | 10 | 20 - buy another 10 unit at 20$ |  |
| 4. | OUT | 20. |  | <----- here I need to have (10 unit at 11$ an 10 ad 20$) |

How can I solve this? can I use windows function? do you have any example using "Postgres" and not "SQL Server"?

Comment: updated table!!

Comment: you want 2 records ? How is set  the column buy_price  ?

Comment: column buy price did set by my self, and I would like to have a average of two prices, not two records

Comment: You want to set the buy_price with a generated column, a function, a scheduled task or else ?

Comment: @Philippe a function

Answer (score 0):

So you can write a query like this but it needs fifo_price to be set in case of "OUT" type. You should add a timestamp column to be sure that you get correct values.

```
select sum(case type when 'IN' then qta * buy_price else -qta * fifo_price end ) / sum(case type when 'IN' then qta else -qta end) from movement where date_movement < '20220103 09:00:00'
```

[Result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/73KznNcQCUkp44GnaUKQUA/0)